# Jquery Hide/Show - Multiple Divs (one at a time)

Tags: jquery, show-hide

This is the point that I'm currently at!

```
$('#img-expand').click(function () {
$('[id^="work-info"]').not('#work-info').hide();
$("#work-info").slideToggle("slow");
});
$('#img-expand_2').click(function () {
$("#work-info").slideToggle("slow");
$('[id^="work-info"]').not('#work-info_2').hide();
$("#work-info_2").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vk7AE/8/

It is very close to what I'm looking for. Individually they work perfect in terms of the vertical sliding. However when the text for image1 is displaying and image 2 is clicked, the text glitches and disappears and then the text for image2 appears on the screen( vice-versa ).

What im looking at is for when the image1 text is being displayed and image2 is clicked, image1 text slides up (disapears from screen) and then the text for image2 slides down from the exact same place. (vice-versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matthew says the second parameter which function runs after the slide is complete is the `key`.

In order to condense the code into one function I changed your `image-expand` id to `image-expand_1` and same with your work info `work-info_1`

```
$("[id^=img-expand]").click(function() {
    var clickedImg = $(this);
    if($('[id^="work-info"]').not('#work-info'+$(this).attr('id').substring($(this).attr('id').indexOf('_'))).is(':visible'))
    $('[id^="work-info"]:visible').slideUp("slow",function(){
        $('#work-info'+clickedImg.attr('id').substring(clickedImg.attr('id').indexOf('_'))).slideDown("slow"); 
    });
    else
        $('#work-info'+clickedImg.attr('id').substring(clickedImg.attr('id').indexOf('_'))).slideToggle("slow");    
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vk7AE/51/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I try to add more elements to the HTML the slideUP and SlideDown effects are lost, ideally what i am looking for is a total of four items with the same effect as you have giving in the answer.http://jsfiddle.net/vk7AE/49/

Answer (score 1):

The `slideToggle()` function accepts a second parameter, which is function that will run after the sliding is complete. So what you need to do is have the second text slide down after the first does by calling it inside that function

http://jsfiddle.net/vk7AE/10/